# Show extra values in mat option when panel is open

Tags: angular-material, mat-select

```
<mat-select >
  <mat-option *ngFor="let i of List" [value]="i.value">
    {{i.viewValue}}<span *ngIf="panelOpen">{{i.viewValue2}}</span>
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

I would like to show additional values in mat option row and hide that additional value after selection. Is There any possibility using panelOpen, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare the `mat-select` as a variable using the `#` notation, you can then change your `ngIf` to `mySelect.panelOpen` where `mySelect` is the ID you gave the `mat-select`:

```
<mat-select #mySelect>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let i of List" [value]="i.value">
    {{i.viewValue}}
    <span *ngIf="mySelect.panelOpen">{{i.viewValue2}}</span>
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Here's [a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n5jgap?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-initial-value-example.html).